# Verificar se existe componentes instalados

Tags: c#, winforms

Em meu projeto tenho um navegador embutido para que o usuário possa acessar um determinado site que ele precisa. O navegador funciona, só que ele tem como requisitos a biblioteca C++ 2012 e o Flash.

Existe alguma forma de descobrir se esses componentes estão instalados no sistema operativo, sem instalar outros componentes?

Comment: [Enumerar os programas instalados](http://stackoverflow.com/a/908907/1242661) e procurar os componentes que necessita?

Comment: @Omni dessa forma eu poderia encontrar somente os dois componentes ? Fico com medo de afetar a performance pelo fato de ficar enumerando tudo que está instalado... Isso poderia acontecer ?

Comment: Tera um impacto por listar os programas instalados, mas qualquer componente que use para listar os programas vai ter um impacto. O pior caso será O(n) (onde n e o numero de programas instalados).

Comment: Entendi.. Mas de qualquer forma eu vou precisar fazer isso né? Porque se não a aplicação não irá funcionar da forma correta.

Comment: Correcto. Pode mitigar o problema e so verificar da primeira vez que correr a sua aplicacao (assim como os instaladores fazem quando verificam se todos os pre requisitos estao preenchidos) (claro que pode ter problemas se o utilizador desinstalar os componentes).

Comment: Seria ótimo, teria como me dar um exemplo de como eu faria isso ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system/908907#908907) como base:

```
// Dicionario que contem os prerequisitos necessarios. Por cada prerequisito,
// contem uma flag que indica se foi encontrado. No fim da pesquisa, se foram todos
// encontrados, retorna verdadeiro. Caso contrario retorna falso.
Dictionary<string, bool> preRequisitosEncontrados = new Dictionary<string, bool>
    {
        { "Adobe Flash Player", false },
        // ... outros componentes que necessite.
    };

List<string> preRequisitos = preRequisitosEncontrados.Keys.ToList();
const string caminhoRegistro = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
using (RegistryKey chave = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(caminhoRegistro))
{
    if (chave != null)
    {
        foreach (string subChaves in chave.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey subChave = chave.OpenSubKey(subChaves))
            {
                if (subChave == null)
                    continue;

                var name = subChave.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
                if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                    continue;

                var index = preRequisitos.FindIndex(s => name.Contains(s));
                if (index == -1)
                    continue;

                // Se encontrou um prerequisito, remove-o da lista e marco-o como encontrado.
                preRequisitosEncontrados[preRequisitos[index]] = true;
                preRequisitos.RemoveAt(index);

            }
        }
    }
}

bool todosEncontrados = preRequisitosEncontrados.All(p => p.Value);
```

Este código procura nos programas instalados pelos prerequisitos definidos. Se os encontrar todos, `todosEncontrados` e verdadeiro. Caso falte algum, `todosEncontrados` e falso.

Pode correr este código sempre que iniciar a sua aplicação, e se falhar, por exemplo, mostrar ao utilizador uma mensagem com os componentes em falta. Ou então pode correr apenas a primeira vez que a aplicação for iniciada e guardar o resultado da pesquisa nos `Settings`:

```
if (!Settings.Default.PrerequisitosCumpridos)
{
    var cumpridos = AnalisarPrerequitos();
    if (cumpridos)
    {
        Settings.Default.PrerequisitosCumpridos = true;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    else
    {
        // informa o utilizador
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ommi como seria esse método:  `var cumpridos = AnalisarPrerequitos();`?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago seria a primeira parte do codigo da resposta dentro de um metodo.

Comment: `bool todosEncontrados = preRequisitosEncontrados.All(p => p.Value);` essa parte usa Entity? Ta dando erro no `All(p=>p.Value)`... Igual aqui: `List<string> preRequisitos = preRequisitosEncontrados.Keys.ToList();`, o `ToList()` não ta sendo reconhecido

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Usa Linq `(System.Linq)`.

Comment: SHOW! Funcionou certinho! Valeu! @Omni

Answer (score 3):

Apenas uma alternativa da excelente resposta do @Omni.

Você possui algumas formas de fazer isso. Uma seria listar os programas instalados e verificar se existe ou não o programa desejado. Dessa forma você busca pelo nome, porém torna menos performático, já que terá que verificar se possui o programa em uma lista de programas. Um exemplo seria assim:

```
string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
            using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
            {
                foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName")).Contains("Adobe Flash"))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Possui Flash");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("NÃO Possui Flash");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Outra alternativa, como mostrado pelo [Omni no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26336410#26336410), você pode verificar pela [Chave de Registro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry).

```
 RegistryKey RK = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Macromedia\\FlashPlayera");
            if (RK != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Flash Instalado");
            }
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta! A resposta do Omni funcionou certinho!